# Authentication Error when trying to upload a new blob to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on a function which takes a document, edits it, and then re-uploads it to azure blob storage, overwriting the original document in the process. Currently the process of downloading and editing the blob is working fine, but I can't seem to fix the authentication error to re-upload.

This is the code which handles the upload stage, the place holders are filled in with (as far as i'm aware) the correct information at run time:

```
def reuploadBlob(container_name, account_name, local_file_path, account_key):
    connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
    blob_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)

    # Upload a file to the Blob Storage
    with open(local_file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)

    return f"File {local_file_path} uploaded to Azure Blob Storage."
```

And this is the function that's handling the initial download of the file from the same storage account, just for reference:

```
def list_and_download_blobs(container_name, account_name):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net")
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container= container_name)
    # Create a local directory to hold blob data
    local_path = "/data"  
    try:
        # List and retrive blobs in the container
        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
        blobs_with_dates = [(blob.name, blob.creation_time) for blob in blob_list]
        # Sort the list based on last modified timestamp
        sorted_blobs = sorted(blobs_with_dates, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)      
        # #Prepare to download the blob
        blob_name = str(sorted_blobs[0][0])
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
        # Download the blob to a local file
        downloaded_blob = blob_client.download_blob()
        local_file_path = blob_name
        # Save the blob content to the local file
        with open(local_file_path, "wb") as local_file:
            local_file.write(downloaded_blob.readall())
        return local_file_path

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:')
        print(ex)
```

Currently the authentication has been handled on the storage container end so that it's got implicit connection rather than using a SAS string every time I want to access it, and is linked to my local ip address, but for this i've been trying to use both the blob sas token and the container account key?

When I send the information over, i'm getting this error:

> Error processing the request. Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:3b7c1cff-401e-0026-4ff6-556c04000000
> Time:2024-02-02T16:42:58.0017819Z
> ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
> authenticationerrordetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'x8ppMP4aaz7CenS+xR2w/F52NKOvyzb8RQFsfIvKpdk=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

> 302520

> application/octet-stream

Is there something really obvious i'm missing in how to fix it? Or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think it might be blob.client.upload in the first example, but i'm not actually sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

def reuploadBlob(container_name, account_name, local_file_path, account_key):
connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

```
try:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
    blob_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)

    # Upload a file to the Blob Storage
    with open(local_file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)

    return f"File {local_file_path} uploaded to Azure Blob Storage."

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception during blob upload:')
    print(ex)
    raise
```

Comment: This has fixed it! I'm massively grateful, would you be able to explain why just for my understanding?